# Seeking Guidance on DynamoDB Triggers with Custom Conditions for Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a DynamoDB table in AWS and I'm trying to set up a trigger for a Lambda function based on the following two conditions:

1. If the count of items with the attribute "status" set to "NEW" in the table reaches 200.
2. If a message has been in the table for more than 10 minutes and the attribute "status" is "NEW".

I initially explored CloudWatch alarms, but I discovered that table size and item count metrics aren't directly sent to CloudWatch. Additionally, there's no straightforward way to query for a metric with a specific condition like "status is NEW".

Another approach I considered is to trigger a Lambda function on every insertion using DynamoDB Streams, while also maintaining a counter. Additionally, I would have a separate Lambda function that runs periodically to handle messages that meet the second criteria (i.e., older than 10 minutes).

As of now, I haven't been able to come up with any other approach.

Could someone provide guidance or suggest an alternative solution for achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a GSI on your table. If your throughput is less than 1000 WCU per second then use a static value as GSI_PK, such as `1`. Use a timestamp as the sort-key.

| GSIPK | SK | OTHER | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-26T00:01:000 | SOME DATA | NEW |
| 1 | 2023-09-26T00:23:000 | SOME DATA | NEW |
| 1 | 2023-09-26T00:41:000 | SOME DATA | NEW |

Now you invoke a Lambda function that reads the index every minute that takes items that are older than 10 mins. When you update an item to no longer being `NEW`, at the same time remove the `GSIPK` from the item, which will remove it from the index.

This is a very efficient and simple way to meet your use case.

For the Lambda invocation you can use a Cron based event on EventBridge.